# How to config xLen in rocket core?

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I am trying to use rocket core as a baseline core and add some additional features for research purpose, but I can't find where or how to change the value "xLen".

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rocket Chip uses a default `XLen` of 64 in it's `DefaultConfig`. However, this can be changed to 32 via a different top-level System configuration of `DefaultRV32Config`.

If you're working with the Rocket Chip emulator, you can compile these two different configurations with

```
cd emulator
CONFIG=DefaultConfig make
CONFIG=DefaultRV32Config make
```

For reference, take a look at the Rocket Chip System configurations defined in the `system` package as well as the `subsystem` configurations:

- [`src/main/scala/system/Configs.scala`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/system/Configs.scala)
- [`src/main/scala/subsystem/Configs.scala`](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/subsystem/Configs.scala)

The former defines `DefaultConfig` and `DefaultRV32Config`. The latter defines `WithRV32`. `WithRV32` is what changes `XLen` to 32 (and also sets `fLen` to 32). Alternatively, you can replicate the behavior of `WithRV32` in your own subclass of `Config`.